# Is there a big difference in hashrate between mining on Linux and Windows?

Tags: mining

I am wondering if there is an advantage in using an OS over the other? I would like to know if anyone might have run some test. I am mostly interest in performance differences between Windows 10 and Ubuntu for the R9 280x using Genoil's miner.

Comment: The key is the drivers, not the operating system. Usually Windows has better driver support.

Comment: But linux is much more stable, it's important for a computer that will run 24/7, also scripting is easier.

Comment: I know all the Linux benefits, however, Pabi asked for hashrate.

Answer (score 0):

i use Ubuntu and i seem to get a little more hash with my CPU on here than windows but no noticeable change with my GPU hash rate when i switched.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. My Gigabyte GTX 750 have 26 KH/s (Verthash) in Windows, while increasing to 80 KH/s in Ubuntu 20.04.

Hope it help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Ethereum has matured enough where the OS does not matter as much. I think windows always can squeeze out a little bit more hashrate then Ubuntu. But that might not be true anymore. OS is basically become personal preference when it comes to Ethereum mining.

Comment: Is this _fact_ or your humble opinion? I get the general feeling that the drivers for Linux are not so well supporting the native device capabilities.

Comment: Definitely my opinion like everything on the internet. I agree with you that Linux drivers are less mature but when it comes to Ethereum it does not matter for older cards. If a new card comes out windows will be where you want to go